# Depressed Numbers

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

$12 = 0$
$1234 = 1$
$123456 = 2$
$12345678 = 4$

$369 = 2$
$248 = 3$

$2 = 0$
$3 = 0$
$5 = 0$
$7 = 0$
$11 = 0$
$13 = 0$

What does:
$123456789 = ?$
Why?

Hopefully isn't too hard, please ask if you need any test cases.

Comment: Wow this was way too easy.  Really should amp up the difficulty level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> 5

because

> You're counting the number of holes in the numbers.

Comment: @JLee Thanks. I didn't know how to do the hide thingy.